# Delete Item Animations

Tags: javascript, html

Fellows, I am using AJAX to delete an item from my table

```
var DeleteLink = function () {

   var LId = $("#HiddenLink_ID").val();

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/my/DeleteLink",
                    data: { Link_ID: LId },
                    success: function (result) {

                        $("#row_" + LId).remove();

                    }

                })

            }
```

I am able to `.remove` the row with the ID

```
$("#row_" + LId).remove();
```

but what I want to do is to

> Give it an animation such as `slide left` or `slide right` when
>   deleted

Is it possible with my current code?

cheers

Comment: It was very close to what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is,

1. Do an animation - Slide Left or Slide Right
2. At the end of the animation, use the callback method to remove the item

Something like -

```
$("#row_" + LId).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function(){
     $("#row_" + LId).remove();
});
```

Read more - http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/

**EDIT:**

JS FIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/1t5wh5dv/1/ (jQuery 1.9 + ui)

JS FIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/1t5wh5dv/2/ (jQuery 3.2.1 + ui)

Comment: `"slide"` is not working, i am not sure why

Comment: You probably need to update jquery version

Comment: I downloaded the latest one `ui`

Comment: Updated and Added JS FIDDLE link. Have a check.

Comment: Not sure what am i missing, "Slow" works but "slide" doesn't ` //$("#row_" + LId).hide("slow");
                        $("#row_" + LId).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function () {
                            $("#row_" + LId).remove();
                        });`